# calculate punctuation percentage in a string in Python

Tags: python, percentage, punctuation

I have been working on calculating the percentage of punctuations in a sentence. For some reason, my function works when doing double spacing, but counts all the characters and the white space. For example, I have a text `DEACTIVATE: OK` so total full length is 14 when I subtract the punctuation then length is 13, so percentage should be `1/13 = 7.63%`, however, my function gives me 7.14%, which is basically `1/14 = 7.14%`.

On the other side, if have just one white space, my function throws me an error

> `"ZeroDivisionError: division by zero".`

Here is my code for your reference and a simple text samples

```
text= "Centre to position, remaining shift is still larger than maximum (retry nbr=1, centring_stroke.r=2.7662e-05, max centring stroke.r=2.5e-05)"
text2= "DEACTIVATE: KU-1421"
```

import string

```
def count_punct(text):
    count = sum([1 for char in text if char in string.punctuation])
    return round(count/(len(text) - text.count("  ")), 3)*100
df_sub['punct%'] = df_sub['Err_Text2'].apply(lambda x: count_punct(x))
df_sub.head(20)
```

Comment: The code above is with two spaces (text.count("  ")). The code I am getting error is with single space (text.count(" ")).

Comment: That's not how percentage works. You don't subtract the number of punctuation characters, it's just `(number of punctuation characters) / (length of string)`, unless you mean subtract the _whitespace_, not the punctuation.

Comment: you mean like this "return round((count)/(len(text) - text.count(" ")), 3)*100"? I still get same error.

Comment: Your error is division by zero? That means you passed in some string that is either fully spaces or empty.

Comment: Thats what I am not able to figure out. Any suggestion or advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: Your code works correctly on my side, for both 1 and 2 white spaces, for both examples

Comment: I can't help you with your data that you haven't posted.

Comment: Hi Kevin, could you please provide some details where did you run and which version of python and string? I am guessing it has something to do with different version or there is something with my notebook or dataframe.

Comment: @Vishwas I was using python 3.5.2 and the `count_punct` function you provided above, for text `"DEACTIVATE: KU-1421"` the result is 10.5 for two whitespaces and 11.1 for one whitespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, Make these small changes and your `count_punct` function should be up and running.. The reason your code was breaking is because you were checking for `___` instead of `_`. i.e 3 consecutive spaces instead of one space. That is why the difference always resulted in the same value.

```
import string
def count_punct(text):
    if text.strip() == "": # To take of care of all space input
        return 0
    count = sum([1 if char in string.punctuation else 0 for char in text ])
    spaces = text.count(" ") # Your error is here, Only check for 1 space instead of 3 spaces
    total_chars = len(text) - spaces

    return round(count / total_chars, 3)*100

text= "DEACTIVATE: OK"

print(count_punct(text))
```

Outputs:

```
7.7
```

And for the zero divide by error. It's a logic error when the total_chars is 0, because the `length` of string and `number of spaces` both are equal. Hence the difference is 0.

To fix this you can simply add an if statement (already added above)

```
if text.strip() == "":
    print(0)
```

Comment: Note that OP commented quote "The code above is with two spaces (text.count(" ")). The code I am getting error is with single space (text.count(" "))." But you're right about division by zero.

Comment: @Tomothy32 I'm not getting any error with single space. And the results are always consistent. And why would he want to check for double spaces anyway?

Comment: What I meant to say was that OP knew about the fact that they accidentally used multiple spaces, they just didn't edit the post. (Nothing wrong with your answer, sorry for any confusion.)

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now and percentage is correct.

Comment: @Vishwas Accept the answer if it helped to mark it as solved, Thanks :)